# Save file with Style Token in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to save a file with some `highlighted text` in notepad++.

But after closing the file and on reopening it, the highlighted text disappears.

Is there a way to persist these style tokens even after closing the file.

Comment: By `highlighted text` do you mean that you have selected it, and you want the selection to persist?

Comment: yes, i have highlighted the selected text by right clicking on it and choosing some style token.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, Notepad++ only deals with text, without formatting. Whatever formatting is applied (like the highlighting) is not a property of the text, it's the way the editor decides to deal with it.

The only thing that you can preserve after saving a file and closing Notepad++ is bookmarks (Ctrl+F2). This is because bookmarks are saved by Notepad++ to a special file. This only works if you reopen the same editor - if you move the file to another pc and open it there, the bookmarks will be lost.

To apply some formatting that is saved into the file, you must change the program and format. What you want is something like .doc (Microsoft Word), or even .rtf (Wordpad). Otherwise, you have to do something like HTML, but it is not [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG), that is, to highlight text you can't simply highlight it in your editor and save it (at least using classic, non-specialized tools).

Comment: Thanks for the brief decription. Will take care about this in future.