# Highlight a Text file in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I was trying to highlight a text file in Notepad++. When I highlighted the particular line and reopen the .txt file the highlighted mark was gone.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually highlight selected text in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179057/manually-highlight-selected-text-in-notepad)

Comment: Hello Welcome to Stackoverflow! It's worthy to include if you had tried searched-solutions which didn't work for you, while you are posting this questions. Such an approach help to eliminate reasons contributing to your problem and narrow down towards a working solution quicker and appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

No, Notepad++ only deals with text, without formatting. Whatever formatting is applied (like the highlighting) is not a property of the text, it's the way the editor decides to deal with it.

Please check Below answer.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462432/save-file-with-style-token-in-notepad#:~:text=No%2C%20Notepad%2B%2B%20only%20deals,bookmarks%20(Ctrl%2BF2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462432/save-file-with-style-token-in-notepad#:%7E:text=No%2C%20Notepad%2B%2B%20only%20deals,bookmarks%20(Ctrl%2BF2)).

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++ once you close it application the highlighted section wont save, There is no way around this its how the app was designed.